# Get the input value after pressing submit button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, submit

I want to get the value of input in JavaScript after pressing submit but the problem is that I get the value I entered in HTML. After I press "Submit Query" the URL change to [path/index.html?number=4](http://path/index.html?number=4) if I set the input to 4. But the value printed in console still the same '2'. I want to get the value of 4 not the default value located within HTML file!!

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("number").value)
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="2">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event listener for your button and then `console.log` the result.

Try this:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
btn.addEventListener('click', func);

function func() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("number").value)
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="2">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add and event listener to your submit button so that when you click on it, you get the value of your input each time

```
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
 console.log(document.getElementById("number").value)
});
```

---

```
<input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="2">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```